# Best way to test web application from different URL's in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, debugging, iis

I would like some suggestions regarding testing a web application (ASP.Net MVC 3 in my case) from multiple URL's.

The site will behave differently based on which domain name the request is coming from. Nothing fancy, just loading different layouts with a few other simple bits and bobs.

Currently, the web.config contains the valid domains the code acts upon and everything seems to be working fine so far.

Whenever I hit Run in Visual Studio, it fires up the developer server instances with the usual *localhos:xxxx* address. 
If I want to test each layout in VS, I need to configure *localhost* to be associated with the layout I wish to load.

I could manage to live with how it is right now, but everything is on TFS, so if someone checks out the file (for testing) and forgets to check back in, it can cause some headaches.

So I was wondering if anyone had some decoupled way to fire up a site with a specific address while maintaining the ability to easily debug (preferably not by deploying to IIS)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could associate some domain name to `localhost` in your `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 foo.com
```

And then navigate to `http://foo.com:xxxx`

Comment: As Darin explained. You can find the hosts file here: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts